# iOS/Cocoa multipleTouchEnabled = true not working if frame was moved

Tags: ios, cocoa, frame, move, multi-touch

I have a following problem:

Created UIView, added to screen. Inside the code of this UIView I say to move the frame itself, here is code:

```
self.frame = CGRectMake(myLeft, myTop, myWidth, myHeight);
```

But then multitouch not working, and in the beganTouch event I get [touches count] = 0;
When I not move frame, then multitouch working. What is the problem ?

multipleTouchEnabled = true - not helping me, it still not working.